# WordPress: Update Gallery Path from Database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

on my blog, i have many posts with many photos as gallery.

I need to change the path of the photos.

Is there a way to change this directly on database?

example: I have this:

```
http://www.maristelavilasboas.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/01-300x200.jpg
```

i need to change to this:

```
http://www.maristelacinefoto.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/01-300x200.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not just the *images*, but the whole blog that needs moving, see [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) in the Codex.